# Is there a way to restore previous (until last update) values in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, restore

Say, I've executed UPDATE table SET field1 = 'val1', field2 = 'val2' WHERE id = 5

Previously field1 was 'VAL1' (e.g.), field2 was 'VAL2'. Is there a way to restore them in this particular table (!!!) to previous state?..

Thanks in advance.

PS: Engine is InnoDB.

Comment: Read about the "undo log" here (but only if you used a transaction )http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/77-Transactions-An-InnoDB-Tutorial.html

Comment: Are you asking about a one-time recovery (eg. because of a disaster), or is this something that you need to do on a regular basis (eg. every time something changes on your database, you want to log this change)?

Comment: That is a result of mistake. That UPDATE query that I've mentioned - was wrong completely. And I want to revert all queries sent to the table until, say, yesterday. That would be an ideal variant if it is possible. Maybe, history of values in table can be retreived from somewhere?

Comment: I don't know if reading the redo log is humanly possible... But it is worth a try. Do you have a "recent" backup of your database? If so, is the "binary log" enabled by any chance (`SHOW VARIABLE LIKE 'log_bin'`)?

Comment: @YaK binary logs are enabled... Is it possible to restore a particular table with them?

Comment: No it is not. But if you have a "recent" backup, then you can replay the binary log (i.e. all data-modifying operations) up until one point in time. If not, I believe you are screwed, but others might know better.

Comment: @YaK I have a backup and can retreive the data from there. But was wondering how to retreive particular table, not the whole DB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no readily available solution to restore one particular table from a dump. However you can restore this dump to another temporary database, then extract the desired table from there, in part or in full.

Otherwise, you can restore the complete backup and replay the binary log up until an arbitrary point in time. [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) will tell you more about this procedure.